# Erase Duplicates in execute-extended-command

Tags: history-variables

Whilst `M-p`ing back through history in `execute-extended-command`, I see many commands are ones which have already appeared earlier (ie more recently).

Is there an option which works similar to `(setq eshell-hist-ignoredups 'erase)` for the command history?

So whenever a new command is executed, all previous invocations are removed from history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup: set `history-delete-duplicates`:

> Non-nil means to delete duplicates in history.
> If set to t when adding a new history element, all previous identical
> elements are deleted from the history list.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Note that this deletes dups for *all* minibuffer histories, not just `command-history`. That's probably what OP wants, but maybe it's worth mentioning.